# How to calculate the total number of circle coordinates?

Tags: geometry, pythagorean

If having a centre(xc,yc) and radius(r), how can i calculate total number of coordinates(x,y) in the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are talking about **integer points** in the circle. Otherwise question is senseless.

In this case you can apply [Gauss formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html)

```
N = 1 + 4 * r + 4 * sum[i=1..r]{floor(sqrt(r^2-i^2))}
```

Note that center has integer coordinates too.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what i looking for.